# Third order differential equation with substitution $z=yy'+x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this homework problem and don't know how to get the solution in terms of $y$:

$$yy'''+(3y'-2y)y''-2(y')^2+yy'+x-2=2xe^x$$

with the help of the substitution:

$$z=yy'+x$$ and initial conditions:$$y(0)=y'(0)=y''(0)=1$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: What is $z'$? What is $z''$?

Comment: I did try that but I cant get the coefficients for the function in terms of the dependent variable y.

Comment: I posted a more thorough hint as an answer. See what that does for you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

$$yy'=z-x$$
By differentiation :
$$yy''+y'^2=z'-1$$
By differentiation again :
$$yy'''+3y'y''=z''$$
Rewriting $\quad yy'''+(3y'-2y)y''-2(y')^2+yy'+x-2=2xe^x\quad$ as :
$$(yy'''+3y'y'')-2(yy''+y'^2)+(yy'+x)-2=2xe^x$$
$$z''-2(z'-1)+z-2=2xe^x$$
$$z''-2z'+z=2xe^x$$

This is a linear second order ODE easy to solve.

Comment: Could you please solve it completely? That is, I need the answer in terms of $y=y(x)$.

Comment: Of course I could. But you already got 3 votes to close your question. I will not waste more time for a question which will probably be closed. Please first comply to the rules of the forum in editing your question.

Comment: Use the button "edit". Show an effort for example in solving $z''-2z'+z=2xe^x$. This an elementary exercise. Don't wait for someone doing it on your place.

Comment: @JJacquelin I'll upvote you. We gotta look out for each other.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$z'=(y')^2+yy''+1$$
and

$$z''=2y'y''+y'y''+yy'''=3y'y''+yy'''$$

Then, we can rearrange your given equation to get:

$$[3y'y''+yy''']-2[yy''+(y')^2+1]+[yy'+x]=z''-2z'+z=2xe^x$$

As a further hint,

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}xe^x=(x+n)e^x$$

Comment: yes, I already got that equation in terms of z but how do i get the homogeneous and particular solution in terms of $y=y(x)$

Comment: What did you get for $z(x)$?

Comment: $z=e^x(A+Bx)+e^x(Cx^3+Dx^2)$ where the first addend is the homogeneous solution and the second the particular where the coefficients $C, D$ need to be calculated by substituting the particular solution into the equation in terms of $z$ but I'm not sure how to get the coefficients of the homogeneous solution.

Comment: Now you have $yy'+x=z(x)$. Substitute into your expression for $z$ and then given one, using the initial conditions.

Comment: Ok, so i got the particular and homogeneous solution for $z$ but how do i get the solution for $y=y(x)$?

Comment: Get the particular solution for $z$, then you have a new equation to solve, namely $z=yy'+x$, solved for $y$.

Comment: so the particular solution for $y$ will be the solution of that equation, and the constants can be obtained by the initial conditions, what about the homogeneous part, do I solve the same equation in terms of the homogeneous part of z?

Comment: You now have $e^x(A+Bx)+e^x(Cx^3+Dx^2)=yy'+x$, and you know the constants from the initial conditions and such. Solve that for $y$ and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can't get a solution... can you please post how you solved it.

Comment: What constants did you get for $A, B, C, D$?

Comment: I didn't get them.